# azure logic apps with azure cost report send mail

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-logic-apps

I tried logic apps with sending a file over mail every time a blob is written in the container and it works fine using the synthax below .

[image]

[image]

Now my problem is that Azure cost report does create a directory that his the following structure :

```
/BlobContainer/BlobDirectoryFromAzureCostReportExport/DirectoryWithNameOfTheReport/
```

So far nothing fancy, we could just leave it that way , but my problem that the cost analysis export creates a directory with this format :

```
 YYYYMM01-YYYYMM30
```

for instance , i have now :

```
   https://ccppdhbstolog.blob.core.windows.net/ccpphbrgdailycostcont/ccpphbrgdailycostdir/ccpphbrgdailycostreport/20200901-20200930/ccpphbrgdailycostreport_30133934-c624-4020-96ac-cf36d9f2e6dc.csv
```

I can select logic Apps to monitor this path :

```
 /ccppdhbstolog.blob.core.windows.net/ccpphbrgdailycostcont/ccpphbrgdailycostdir/ccpphbrgdailycostreport/20200901-20200930/
```

But next month what will happen  ? ( I would need to reconfigure... ) or, maybe I can write this YYYYMMDD-YYYYMMDD for the coming month. But I do not now the synthax, nor if this is going to work if there 31 days or 28 (febuary )  days in the month ..

I need to send report automatically, any clue how I can make this work ?

Comment: I don't see a setting in the Logic App where it is set to monitor a specific path? Do you set one?

Comment: It might also be useful for you to know that Blob Storage doesn't have folders. It just simulates them by having them as part of the blob name. It's actually a flat list in the container.

Comment: If you monitor a given subdirectory (even if in Blob there is no such concepts of dirs...) still it seems to work, my ideal situation would be to monitor either entire blob, but this is not working. Or adding variables in the path of logic apps to match the format above